# How can I make an SKSpriteNode's velocity the same across different devices in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

My scene's size is view.bounds.size

I have a ball whose size is CGSize(width: frame.size.width/25, height: frame.size.width/25)

Originally, i had the ball speed at CGVector(dx: 25, dy: 25), but the ball went faster on smaller devices (SE) and slower on larger ones (8 Plus), which makes sense. So i changed the ball's x and y velocity to be frame.size.width * 0.067, which comes to 25 on an iPhone 7, which is the speed i like. Unfortunately, the ball still moved at different speeds on different devices. Then, I thought it must be that the ball has a different mass because the ball size is a percentage of the frame width. So i set the mass to be a constant, but still the ball moves at different speeds
so now i have no idea whats going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use constant size for scene (for playing area) and render that constant size to any screens with some transformation. Therefore all logic of your application will interact with constant size on any devices.
If screen has other ratio, you can add decorative elements near edges of the screen.

Comment: Yes, this is the preferred way to go.  Your scene should always start as a constant size, and you should use the `.resize` scaleMode to adjust it if you are in a game that needs pixel perfect graphics

Comment: One thing i will disagree with is the "decorative elements", From a UX stand point, people do not like their views to be cropped. It is actually better to allow people to see a little bit more of the scene instead of a little bit less.  Of course this is not a definitive rule, because there are games on there that only work with fixes aspects (like Tetris) where as a platformer (like Mario) you want to give them the opportunity to see more sky and ground.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the scenes size to view.bounds.size, but the movements are still slow on iphone 8 plus/iphone x and fast on iphone se, even though the velocity is a constant number, and the scene sizes are the same.

Comment: Are you sure that a view has same bounds on different devices? I recommended use some const size, for example (640*960), for scene and make transformation for render it into a screen view.